# Why only non-nullable value types support packing in Protocol Buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers

In the Protocol Buffer, the serialization of the repeated field is not the same, such as the `repeated message field`, which is serialized using the form of `Tag-Len-Value`, and the `repeated int32 field`, which is serialized using the form of `Tag-Value`. This difference is described in the source code as follows: **only non-nullable value types support packing**, and why it is designed that way

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the packed tag was introduced later and in a backwards compatible way.

In order for that to work the wire types have to be different, so it doesn't work for types that already use the length delimited tag like messages or bytes.